# Question about "Differential Geometry of curves and surfaces by Manfredo do Carmo" sec. 2-6.

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry

In the section about the orientation of surfaces it is stated that:

> By fixing a parametrization $x(u,v)$ of a neighborhood of a point p of a regular surface S, we determine an orientation of the tangent plane $T_pS$, namely, the orientation of the associated ordered basis ${x_u,x_v}$. If p belongs to the coordinate neighborhood of another parametrization $x'(u',v')$, the new basis ${x'_{u'},x'_{v'}}$ is expressed in terms of the first one by
>
> $x'_{u'}=x_u \frac{\partial u}{\partial u'}+x_v \frac{\partial v}{\partial u'}$
>
> $x'_{v'}=x_u \frac{\partial u}{\partial v'}+x_v \frac{\partial v}{\partial v'}$
>
> where $u=u(u',v')$ and $v=v(u',v')$ are the expressions of the change of coordinates. The basis ${x_u,x_v}$ and ${x'_{u'},x'_{v'}} $determine, therefor, the same orientation of $T_p(S)$ if and only if the Jacobian $\frac{\partial(u,v)}{\partial (u',v')}$ of the coordinate change is positive

To get to my question, given another parametrization like above how do I calculate the unit normal vector $N(p):=\frac {x_u \times x_v}{|x_u \times x_v|}$ under the new parametrization.

(I am trying to understand why the Jacobian of the coordinate change needs to be positive)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I interpret this as a purely linear-algebraic issue. If you have two bases of $T_pM$, namely $\{x_u,x_v\}$ and $\{x'_{u'},x'_{v'}\}$ and a relation between the bases given by
\begin{equation} 
\begin{split}
x'_{u'} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial u'} x_u + \frac{\partial v}{\partial u'} x_v\\
x'_{v'} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial v'} x_u + \frac{\partial u}{\partial u'} x_v\\
\end{split}
\end{equation}
then they determine the same orientation if and only if the matrix
$$M=\left(
\begin{matrix}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial u'} & \frac{\partial v}{\partial u'}\\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial v'} & \frac{\partial v}{\partial v'}
\end{matrix}\right)
$$
has positive determinant. Note that taking the vector product $x'_{u'}\times x'_{v'}$ in terms of ${x_u,x_v}$ yields
$$
x_{u'}\times x_{v'} = x_u \times x_v \frac{\partial u}{\partial u'} \frac{\partial v}{\partial v'} + x_v\times x_u\frac{\partial v}{\partial u'}\frac{\partial u}{\partial v'} = \det(M) x_u\times x_v
$$
and therefore you can easily check the following:
$$
N' = \frac{x'_{u'} \times x'_{v'}}{|x'_{u'} \times x'_{v'}|} = \frac{\det(M)}{|\det(M)|} \frac{x_{u} \times x_{v}}{|x_{u} \times x_{v}|} = sign(\det(M)) N$$
and therefore the orientation as seen from the unit normal agrees if and only if the determinant of the jacobian is positive.

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: Note that in general one defines the orientation of two different basis in higher dimensional precisely when the matrix of change of basis has positive determinant: the lucky coincidence that you have a vector product in the ambient space $\mathbb{R}^3$ is no longer granted when speaking about orientation of higher dimensional objects!